# How can I send existing CMP content/entities to Sitecore in bulk?

Tags: content-hub, content-hub-scripting

I have the basic Sitecore connect for CMP set up so that when a content item goes into the final workflow state, it is sent to Sitecore. I have also managed to set it up to send over some taxonomy entities when they are modified. Now I want to send over existing content/entities without going to each item and making a change to it.

I assume this is going to need to be a script since I haven't found anything in the UI that would allow me to execute an action either individually or in bulk. The documentation indicates that the Service Bus [actions can be executed in bulk](https://docs.stylelabs.com/content/4.0.x/integrations/integration-components/actions/bulk-execution.html), but I have not found anything telling how to actually do it. Nor have I found anything in the [scripting documentation](https://docs.stylelabs.com/content/4.0.x/integrations/scripting-api/scripting-api-overview.html) about how to execute an action.